# Algorithm to all N words in a language

Tags: algorithm, dictionary, stack

Suppose you have invented a language, and are writing a dictionary of all N words in the language.  The dictionary has N pages, one for each word.  You have handwritten your dictionary pages and have put them into a stack A in alphabetical order, with the first word's page on the top of the stack.  You take the stack to the printing store to have it professionally printed.  Unfortunately, the clerk at the store drops the stack, and it breaks into two smaller stacks A1 and A2 of possibly different sizes.  To fix the problem, the clerk randomly picks one stack and puts it on top of the other, creating a new stack B.  (Assume both sub-stacks are still in alphabetical order- i.e., neither of them flipped upside down).  It is possible that B = A, but it is also possible that the pages in B are now in the wrong order (e.g., if A1 should have been on top and now A2 is on top); and what's worse, you no longer know where the line between A1 and A2 originally was. Design an efficient, optimal algorithm to determine to tell whether B is in the right order; and if not, to determine where to split B back into A1 and A2 so that they can be put back together properly.  What is the worst-case running time of your algorithm, as a function of N?

Comment: You need to first show your work and then ask for help. https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/334822/how-do-i-ask-and-answer-homework-questions "Make a good faith attempt to solve the problem yourself first. If we can't see enough work on your part your question will likely be booed off the stage; it will be voted down and closed."

Answer (score 1):

If you don't know what the last word in the language should be and only have a comparison function that tells you whether one word is less than another - you can tell if B is in the right order simply by comparing the first page with the last. If there is an incorrect split (and all words are distinct) then these two will be in order iff B is in order. Otherwise, go to the middle of the list, and if the word there is larger than the first page, it's part of the original bottom stack; else it's part of the misshuffled top stack. In the first case the split comes after, in the second it comes before.

```
1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9 10
=>
8 9 10 1 2 3 4 5 6 7
^                  ^
 7 is less than 8 so B is out of order
         ^
         2 < 7 so the split is in the left half
     ^ 10 > 8 so the split is in the right half
       ^ 1 < 8 so the split is in the left half
      ^ but we ran out of halves so this is the split and 10 is the max
```

This method worst-case complexity of O(log n).

Note that the above all assumes the words are all distinct and can be put in a total order - every word comes either before or after every other word, no two words are equivalent alphabetically. If equivalent words are allowed the best-case complexity is clearly O(n) in the worst case because you could have n-1 equivalent words, one bigger word, cut the deck and the big word could be anywhere (or nowhere if it's actually n equivalent cards).
UPDATE: pseudocode

```
Uncut(list[1...n])
1. if n < 2 then return "no cut necessary"
2. if list[1] < list[n] return "no cut necessary"
3. return "cut at " + Findcut(list[1...n], list[1])

FindCut(list[1...m], target)
1. if m < 2 then return 0
2. if list[ceiling(m/2)] < target then
3.     return ceiling(m/2) - 1 + FindCut(list[ceiling(m/2), m], target)
4. else
5.     return FindCut(list[1, ceiling(m/2)]
```

Something like that, code it up and be on the lookout for off-by-one errors or something in the output. This might say "cut at position 5" or something to mean that the 5th thing goes in the left part, or the right part. YMMV.

Comment: Hi Patrick
can you provide the pseduo code?

Comment: @GauravPanda See update